# Encountering error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList$Builder

Tags: selenium, webdriver, noclassdeffounderror

I'm new to Selenium WebDriver using EclipseIDE with TestNG. I'm currently running this sample code in Eclipse via TestNG:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.List;

public class CheesecakeFactory {

    FirefoxDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void startDriver() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void stopDriver() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void listCheesecakes() {
        driver.get("http://www.thecheesecakefactory.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Menu")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cheesecake")).click();
        List<WebElement> cheesecakes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("id('leftNav_levelTwo')//li"));

        System.out.println(cheesecakes.size() + " cheesecakes:");
        for (int i=0; i<cheesecakes.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i+1 + ". " + cheesecakes.get(i).getText());
        }
    }

}
```

But Eclipse returns this:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--616826937\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest startDriver
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList$Builder
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.WindowsUtils.getPathsInProgramFiles(WindowsUtils.java:275)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.locateFirefoxBinaryFromPlatform(Executable.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<clinit>(Executable.java:25)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:78)
    at CheesecakeFactory.startDriver(CheesecakeFactory.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1197)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1122)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I've done the following:

1. Added the guava-12.0.jar file (along with the other jar files in the Selenium-2.25.0 webdriver) as an external jar file in Eclipse. (This jar file contains the ImmutableList$Builder class)
2. Added the path of this jar file in the CLASSPATH (Environment Variables>System Variables)

Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using selenium-java-2.25.0.jar. You should rather use **selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar,** it will take care of all the dependencies (i.e. required jar files).

Also you dont need to explicitly define the environment variables if the jar files are added in the Eclipse, unless you are running the test outside from eclipse.

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Hi Prashant. Thank you for your answer. Yes, I am using the Selenium-java-2.25.0.jar. If I use the selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar, will I need to start this server from the command prompt or I could use it as I would a normal API in Eclipse?

Comment: as a normal api. pretty much the way you added the java-2.25.0.jar. There will be no need to start the server if you are not using remotedriver.